# Mongodb nodejs driver forEach goes through all documents event they should be filtered

Tags: node.js, mongodb

After filtering on the cursor, forEach still goes through all documents, seems like filter did nothing.
Here is an example:

```
await mongodb.files
  .find({})
  .filter(file => (+new Date(file.uploadDate) + 1000 * 60* 60) < +new Date())
  .forEach(
    doc => {
      console.log((+new Date(doc.uploadDate) + 1000 * 60* 60) < +new Date());
    },
    err => {}
);
```

The output will be:

```
true
true
false
false
```

The output is correct, but why they are not filtered out?

Comment: [`filter`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/api/Cursor.html) cursor must contain an object whereas you are using it with wrong syntax.

Comment: can you give me an example, please?

Comment: Just go through [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)